# I ran a regression analysis with an interaction, and I want to compare the beta coefficients across the levels of my categorical variable

Tags: regression, python, interaction, post-hoc, statsmodels

I have a regression I ran with a continuous dependent variable (CSI), and independent continuous variable (ACI) and a categorical variable with 4 levels (Relationship_Type):

```
model_complex = smf.ols('CSI~ACI + C(Relationship_Type) + C(Relationship_Type)*ACI', df).fit()
```

I want to compare all the beta coefficients for my 4 levels in the interaction (I want to see if the slopes are significantly different) and I feel like there is a better way than to run the regression 4 times in a row, just changing the reference level. I'm not sure how to do this, especially not in python.

Comment: I hope you get a Python recommendation, but just in case you don't, one way to do this in R is to use simple_slopes function from the reghelper package and specify confint=TRUE. Then, if the CIs for different betas are not overlapping, the betas could be said to be significantly different from each other.

Comment: statsmodels results classes have t_test method for (vectorized) single hypothesis and wald_test for joint hypotheses for user specified contrasts

Comment: I'm not sure which hypothesis this asks for, no interaction effect just needs to compare two models, ie. a joint restriction on the interaction parameters. Or all pairwise comparisons which would be more multiple hypotheses. Or, all treatments versus control/reference which is already given by pvalues and confint of the individual interaction parameters.